# The application crashes when the media recorder starts?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am using the media recorder to record the calls in android. Some times the mediaRecorder is recording audio and some times it doesn't record audio. When we play the recorded audio The error shown as "The player doesn't supports this type of audio file ".

The below code is for the recording the audio

```
 try {
                    f1 = File.createTempFile("Sound", ".mp3", dir);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                fileName = f1.getName();
                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(f1.getAbsolutePath());
                try {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaRecorder.start();
                recordstarted = true;
```

My logcat error shown below

```
 E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38
07-03 11:10:23.718 8558-8558/com.seyali.callLog E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.seyali.callLog.receiver.CallReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2593)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                         at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.seyali.callLog.receiver.CallReceiver.onReceive(CallReceiver.java:175)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2586)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illegal state means that your media recorder is not ready to recording. There might be several reasons for it. First of all, make sure you can reach the file which you want to play. If it is fine, checkout the media recorder diagram for which state you should play. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Also, what happens if `mediaRecorder.prepare()` ? You should put `mediaRecorder.start()` into the try block.

Comment: The recorded file stored in external storage.when i click to play "the player doesn't support this audio" error is showing

Comment: Also i inserted the mediaRecorder.start() in try block